# collision problems with EaselJS

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, easeljs, createjs

My shape either falls through the floor or disappears. My code is easy enough, and if you copy and paste, you be able to see everything. Anyway, hears is the code. I'm thinking that I probably did't add something to the collision located in the tick function.

```
var box, gravity, stage;
stage = new createjs.Stage(document.getElementById('canvas'));
gravity = 10;

// this function is called onload in the body tag
function init(){
    box = new createjs.Shape();
    box.graphics.beginFill('blue').drawRect(0,0,50,50);
    stage.addChild(box);
    box.x = 50;
    box.y = 50;
    game();
}

function game(){

    window.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', tick);

    var floor;

    floor = new createjs.Shape();
    floor.graphics.beginFill('red').drawRect( 0, 0, 500, 20);
    floor.x = 0;
    floor.y = 480;
    stage.addChild(floor);


function keydownHandler(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 65 || e.keyCode === 37){
    box.x -=5;
    stage.update();
    console.log(box.x);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 68 || e.keyCode === 39){
    box.x += 5;
    stage.update();
    console.log(box.x);
    } else if(e.keyCode === 87 || e.keyCode === 38){
    var lBox;
    box.y -= 50;
    lBox = new createjs.Shape();
    lBox.graphics.beginFill('blue').drawRect(box.x - 16, box.y + 50, 16,         15);
    stage.addChild(lBox);
    stage.update();
    console.log(box.y);
    }

}

    function tick(){

    console.log(box.y);
    console.log(floor.y);

    box.y += gravity;

    var collision;
    collision = floor.y;
    // Here is the problem right here!

    if(box.y + 45 >= collision){
    box.y = floor.y;
    }
    stage.update();
    }

}

I also think I use stage update too much, so if there is a SIMPLE way,            because I'm new please feel free to demonstrate that as well.thanks in advance.
```

Comment: many thank Lanny!!! quick follow up if you have time. now that floor is working, should I make an array of platforms to create a level of floor-like objects, or is the a more pragmatic way to load a level, and make them have collision?

Comment: Yeah, tracking an array or collection of platforms would work. It can get expensive if you have too many. If you want to build a platformer, maybe check out Box2D -- there is a sample in the CreateJS GitHub. https://github.com/CreateJS/sandbox/tree/master/EaselJS_Box2dWeb

Answer (score 1):

I created a quick JSFiddle using your code (just had to remove the init, since JSFiddle runs the entire block onload).

http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/mkwo8kdv/

It seems to work fine, except when you pass the "floor", it will snap to the same Y position as the floor. Since the box's registration point is at the top left, it will be below the floor. I added the box's height, and it stops where it is intended.

```
if (box.y + 45 >= collision) {
    box.y = floor.y - 50;
}
```

I also removed the additional `stage.update()` calls that were in the keyhandler. The one in the tick will suffice, since it constantly runs.